# Android apps worked in usb debugging but not in android emulator (white screen)

Tags: android-emulator

I run "ionic cordova run android" using visual studio code.. but the apps shows white screen in the emulator.. it display properly if using USB debugging.. the device also display properly if install using the apk.. the reason why I want to use emulator because I want to debug "http://10.0.2.2".. this is my emulator setting..

[Emulator setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hwu0c.png)

Things that I have done is as per below

1. Choose ANGLE (D3D11) for OpenGL ES Renderer at the emulator advance setting
2. Choose Software - GLES 2.0 graphic for the Emulated Performance during create emulator
3. Try both R and Q for the system image during create the virtual device
4. Update the SDK based on the system image set at the emulator

[System image selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7pMq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue

- I compile the source code at different laptop (Laptop A) and it manage to display error at the web console using google inspect
- it display "newtrustedfunctionforjit fn.bind is not a function"..

Founding

- the issue is related to the chrome version 83 and the browser need an upgrade to solve the issue
- The emulator is not using a browser (it using web view) hence I cannot update the google version

Solution

- download new skin for newer android model into laptop A
- download same skin on the laptop B (the laptop that I initially come with this post)

Below is the explanation from GitHub for angular

[Explanation about the chrome issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHsEG.png)

Below is my new System Image

- Release Name S
- API Level 31
- ABI x86_64
- Target Android 12 (Google APIs)

[New System Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9Jdh.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).